# transform data frame in time series for date type POSIXct

Tags: dataframe, time-series, zoo

I have a data frame with the following two variables:
amount: num 1213.5 34.5 ...
txn_date: POSIXct, format "2017-05-01 12:13:30" ...

I want to transform it in a time series using ts().

I started using this code:

Z <- zoo(data$amount, order.by=as.Date(as.character(data$txn_date), format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))

But the problem is that in Z I loose the dates. In fact, all the dates are reported as NA.

How can I solve it?
For my analysis is important to have date in the format:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S
for example 2017-05-01 12:13:30. I don't want to remove the time component in the variable txn_date.

Yhan you for your help,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

I think your prolem comes from the way you're manipulating your data frame, could post more details about it please ?

I think i have a fix for you.
Data frame I used :

```
> df1
$data
     value
1   1.9150
2   3.1025
3   6.7400
4   8.5025
5  11.0025
6   9.8025
7   9.0775
8   7.0900
9   6.8525
10  7.4900

$date
     %Y-%m-%d
1  1974-01-01
2  1974-01-02
3  1974-01-03
4  1974-01-04
5  1974-01-05
6  1974-01-06
7  1974-01-07
8  1974-01-08
9  1974-01-09
10 1974-01-10
> class(df1$data$value)
[1] "numeric"
> class(df1$date$`%Y-%m-%d`)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Then I can create a time serie by calling zoo like that :

```
> Z<-zoo(df1$data,order.by=(as.POSIXct(df1$date$`%Y-%m-%d`)))
> Z
             value
1974-01-01  1.9150
1974-01-02  3.1025
1974-01-03  6.7400
1974-01-04  8.5025
1974-01-05 11.0025
1974-01-06  9.8025
1974-01-07  9.0775
1974-01-08  7.0900
1974-01-09  6.8525
1974-01-10  7.4900
```

The important thing here is that I use `df1$date$%Y-%m-%d` instead of just 
 `df1$date`

In fact if I try the way you did it I get `NA` values too :

```
> Z<-zoo(df1$data,order.by=as.POSIXct(as.Date(as.character(df1$date),format("%Y-%m-%d"))))
> Z
     value
<NA> 1.915
```

To get the name of data$txn_date you can use the following command : `names(data$txn_date)` and try my solution with your data frame and name.

```
> names(df1$date)
[1] "%Y-%m-%d"
```

Comment: I am sick, but when I will be back at work I will try your elegant solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not give you more details because data are confidential. But your solution sound good. I will let you know soon if it works.